# Convert multiple value columns into new key, value pairs

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, transpose, unpivot

I need to convert a .csv file's contents from:

```
continent, region, country, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, ...
Africa, East Africa, Ethiopia, 12, 14, 15, 9, ...
```

to:

```
continent, region, country, year, value
Africa, East Africa, Ethiopia, 1990, 12
Africa, East Africa, Ethiopia, 1991, 14
Africa, East Africa, Ethiopia, 1992, 15
Africa, East Africa, Ethiopia, 1993, 9
...
```

There are a bunch of rows, so this is impossible to do by hand. I know there has got to be a way to do it, I really am just having issues even explaining what I am doing. It is essentially transposing part of the table but not all of it.

EDIT: here is a sample of a full row of data:

```
continent, region, country, country_abbr, economy, lat, long, 1990/91, 1991/92, 1992/93, 1993/94, 1994/95, 1995/96, 1996/97, 1997/98, 1998/99, 1999/00, 2000/01, 2001/02, 2002/03, 2003/04, 2004/05, 2005/06, 2006/07, 2007/08, 2008/09, 2009/10, 2010/11, 2011/12, 2012/13, 2013/14, 2014/15
Africa, Middle Africa, Angola, AO, 7. Least developed region, -12.5, 18.5, 50, 79, 78, 33, 77, 62, 71, 64, 85, 55, 50, 21, 57, 38, 15, 25, 35, 36, 38, 13, 35, 29, 33, 35, 39
```

Comment: The values of 'year' are currently headers in the file, and the 'value' is in the column beneath it. Those words technically don't exist yet, I just need to encode the data differently. Every row that exists in my existing table will become 25 new rows (that's how many years I have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by *Those words technically don't exist yet* so I have moved the `country` column just before the first year column and am ignoring, for the moment, anything to the left of `country`. 'Unpivot' as described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) with selection of `country` column to the last year column and only as many rows as are populated.

The resulting Table should be of three columns with a set of 25 rows for each country. The first column ("Row" - country name) might be used to lookup the details I was ignoring above.